# Formatting based on last digit

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, rdlc, modulus, reportbuilder

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder to list some production data i a table, mainly part numbers. I would like it to change fill color of the part number cells, based on the number in the cell.

Previously we have been using a solution, using `mod10` to color it, based on the last digit. This will cause a repeat for every tenth part number, but that is fine. However we have now started a new series, which means that I need to deal with the number 1-9. Obviously, the `mod10` trick does not work here. Is there a smarter way of getting the last digit, which also works on numbers from 1-9, or do I have to make some sort of `IIF` statement?

Her is an example of the code I use, though with `mod5`, rather than `mod10`:

```
=Choose(1+ Fields!cPri_runnr.Value.Value Mod 5,"DarkOliveGreen","Olive","LimeGreen","Yellow","Khaki")
```

Comment: Could you show an example of the expression you are currently using? Also, why would `num % 10` not work on 1 - 9? It would just return the original number (e.g. `5 % 10` is `0r5`, so you would get `5`).

Comment: Added an example. With mod5 though, but the idea is the same.

Comment: I agree with @Cory, it's unclear as to what problem you're facing *(as described, `% 10` appears to do exactly what you asked.)*  Please could you give some example values, with the results that `% 5` and `% 10` are giving you, and also with the results that you want instead.

Comment: You are both right, it wasn't the modulus function that failed me. It was rather a simple typo, where i had .Values added twice (as you can see in the code). I just wasn't sure how the modulus funtion acted, so I blamed it. My bad, and thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are several options here, if `Mod` is sufficient you can use `Choose`, `Switch`, or even `IIF`.  In my opinion, the best solution would use [Custom Code](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155798(v=sql.100).aspx) to hash the part number (or even take multiple inputs from the details row) and return a color directly.  This could then be easily re-used in multiple sections of the report (chart colors, additional cell back-colors, even cell text color).

Comment: I think that might be level 2 for me :-). For a start, I managed to make modulus work.